# Php Curl submit login

Tags: php, facebook, curl, authentication

I am trying to submit credentials inserted by users through a Facebook application, which must be validated by an external system. I'm trying to submit them by this sitehttps://studenti.unisalento.it/. I read a lot of articles about the data posting by the PHP extension libcurl, management of cookie, ecc (like thishttp://www.herikstad.net/2011/06/logging-to-https-websites-using-php.html) but I can not post credentials to a login prompt system like this https://studenti.unisalento.it/auth/Logon.do
Any ideas??? Thanks!

Edit:
I noticed that you can login entering credentials in the url with this scheme: https://username:password@studenti.unisalento.it/auth/Logon.do?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&saveLastPath=0&_58_struts_action= You can take advantage of this using libcurl functions?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer even though it's not the answer you are looking for is:  Don't do it.

You want students to enter their university login and passwords into your Facebook application?

Have you talked to the university about this?

How do they know your app isn't storing the submitted login and password somewhere so that you can hack into the student accounts later?

The likely answer is:  They don't.

This is why things like OAuth and Shibboleth were invented.  They allow you to authenticate users from a third party without collecting the user's actual credentials.

unisalento.it appears to have a Shibboleth installation. If you are running a legitimately sanctioned application, look at using that or some other authentication scheme that doesn't involve you collecting the username and password.

Since you're using PHP, [simpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the integration of Facebook with the information system of my University is the purpose of my graduation thesis. I think that Shibboleth is just what I was looking for...

Comment: I added a note about simpleSAMLphp, which might be useful to you.

Comment: Sorry, have you already experience with simpleSAMLphp? I read a few pages of documentation, I have heard enough about the interaction between UserAgent, ServiceProvider and IdentityProvider but I can not find comprehensive documentation on how to authenticate credentials by an external ServiceProvider.Thanks